# How to automate file upload in Internet Explorer using Selenium?

Tags: selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload a file from a site using Selenium's java inteface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522372/how-to-upload-a-file-from-a-site-using-seleniums-java-inteface)

I am new to Selenium.Can you please tel me how to automate file upload in Internet Explorer using Selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not easy, and it is not easy for very good reasons - security. If you are able to upload something like this, what's stopping someone uploading your details using the same method?

You have also given us no example to work with so:

Given this sample webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.fileSave { color: red; }
</style>
</head>
<label for="fileUpload">File location:
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<br>
<br>
<a href="" class="fileSave">Save file</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I can do this, in C#:

```
Driver = new ChromeDriver();
var fileUploadControl = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileUpload"));
fileUploadControl.SendKeys("C:\File.txt");
var submitLink = Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("fileSave"));
submitLink.Click();
```

Comment: "If you are able to upload something like this, what's stopping someone uploading your details using the same method?"

To some extent, CAPTCHA will.

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked [several times](https://www.google.com/search?q=webdriver%20upload%20file) and is also in some Selenium FAQ.

Selenium 2 (WebDriver) Java example:

```
// assuming driver is a healthy WebDriver instance
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");
```

For Selenium RC, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387257/selenium-rc-upload-file).

The idea is to directly send the absolute path to the file to an element which you would usually click at to get the modal window - that is `<input type='file' />` element.