# Selenium: after file upload can not get file size

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium to test web app behaviour on file upload page. 
The goal of test is to check application validations on file selection.

I use `webDriver.SendKeys` (C#) on file input to simulate file upload, file is selected successfully, but `fileInput.files[0].size` (js) is always 0 (or undefined?) and app shows error "Do not upload empty files". File size is correct on manual testing.

Any suggestions, on how to solve the problem?

**UPDATE** Code details:

HTML

```
<input id="file-path" type="file" data-bind="attr: { accept: mimeTypes }, event: { change: onFileSelect }" />
<small id="file-path-error" class="field-validation-error" data-bind="validationMessage: file"></small>
```

JS (file edit model uses knockout)

```
this.file = ko.observable().extend({
    validation: [
      {
        validator: function(file) {
          // valid if no file or file size < 5Mb
          return !file || file.size < 5242880;
        },
        message: 'File size should be less than 5Mb'
      }, {
        validator: function(file) {
          // valid if no file or file size > 0
          return !file || file.size > 0;
        },
        message: 'Do not upload empty files'
      }
    ]
  });
this.onFileSelect = function(model, event) {
    var fileInput;    
    fileInput = event.target;
    if ((fileInput.files != null) && fileInput.files.length > 0) {
      _this.file(fileInput.files[0]);          
    } else {
      _this.file(null);
    }
  };
```

C#

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("file-path")).SendKeys("C:\testFile.txt");
Assert.AreEqual(webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("file-path-error").Text,"");
```

Assertion always fails because file-path-error contains "Do not upload empty files" - that is the problem.

Comment: Selenium by itself cannot handle file uploads. Please show your code how you are doing this.

Comment: @SiKing, I added code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misleaded by answers on [How to automate file upload in Internet Explorer using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714198/how-to-automate-file-upload-in-internet-explorer-using-selenium)

Discusstion on [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html) says that actually we can not upload files programmatically.

So there was no sence in expecting decent behaviour for such test.